# Passing multiple streams in WCF

Tags: wcf

**What I have?**

I have a WCF contract which accepts a Stream object.

**What I need?**

I want to convert the contract to accept multiple streams. But, there is some problem with passing multiple streams in WCF. Now I have two options,

(1) Call the WCF method multiple times

(2) Change contract to accept a two dimensional byte array with all file contents

Can somebody tell me which option is better?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We solved this problem by building a Stream wrapper implementation on the client that concatenates a list of streams together, end to end (eg, .Read delegates to the first stream- when it hits EOF on stream 1, it starts reading stream 2, and so on). It has a metadata property that has the names of the streams and their positions, which we include on the call in a [MessageHeader] attributed arg that says what's in the stream and the offsets of each (the client streams must support .Length). The consumer of the streams on the server knows how to read this metadata object and hand out a list of streams in order. The only restriction is that they must be processed in order. Works great!

Answer (score 4):

In WCF, you **cannot** have multiple stream parameters in a single service method. It's just a system restriction.

See the [MSDN documentation on WCF streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx):

> **Restrictions on Streamed Transfers**
>
> Using the streamed transfer mode
>   causes the run time to enforce
>   additional restrictions.
>
> Operations that occur across a
>   streamed transport can have a contract
>   with **at most one input or output
>   parameter.** That parameter corresponds
>   to the entire body of the message and
>   must be a Message, a derived type of
>   Stream, or an IXmlSerializable
>   implementation. Having a return value
>   for an operation is equivalent to
>   having an output parameter.

So for now, all you can do is call your method several times.

Marc

Answer (score 1):

In my system, I need to send a FileStream and a generic List of custom data to WCF service. This is how I do it to combine both into a single stream and send it to the service which returns a result stream to the client:

Service Contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    ResultClass MyOperation(Parameters param);
}
```

Return Stream:

```
[MessageContract]
public class ResultClass
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public System.IO.Stream Stream { get; set; }
}
```

Input Stream:

```
[MessageContract]
public class Parameters
{
    [MessageHeader]
    public long Length1 { get; set;}
    [MessageHeader]
    public long Length12 { get; set;}
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public Stream Stream { get; set;}
}
```

At the WCF client:

```
public static void BuildStream(string filePath, List<CustomData> otherParams, ref Parameters param)
{
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        MemoryStream allStreams = new MemoryStream();
        MemoryStream dataStream = new MemoryStream();
        formatter.Serialize(dataStream, otherParams);
        dataStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        fs.CopyTo(allStreams);
        dataStream.CopyTo(allStreams);
        param.TemplateLength = fs.Length;
        param.DataLength = dataStream.Length;
        param.Stream = allStreams;
        param.Stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
}
```

In the service implementation, pull out the first and second streams from the combined stream:

```
List<CustomData> dataSheets;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    MemoryStream dataStream;
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    byte[] templatebuffer, databuffer;
    filebuffer = new byte[m_param.Length1];
    databuffer = new byte[m_param.Length2];
    // Get the whole stream
    m_param.Stream.CopyTo(ms);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    // Get the first stream
    ms.Read(templatebuffer, 0, (int)m_param.TemplateLength);
    // Get the custom data
    ms.Read(databuffer, 0, (int)m_param.DataLength);
    using (dataStream = new MemoryStream(databuffer))
    {
        dataStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        dataSheets = (List<DataSheet>) formatter.Deserialize(dataStream);
        m_param.Stream.Close();
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider [MTOM](http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2008/02/02/wcf-mtom-binary-data-transmission.aspx) [binding](http://mssolutionhelper.com/topics/dotnet/WCF_MTOM.aspx) and have a data contract with multiple `byte[]` properties.

Comment: And how to stream that byte[ ] properties?